# Writing zip contents to a text file

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I'm trying to write the contents of a zip file to a text file.
My code right now only writes the first file.
(This is using [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/))

```
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(AddonFile));
ZipEntry item;

while ((item = zip.GetNextEntry()) != null)
{
    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(
        @"resource\texts\"+ Path.GetFileName(AddonFile)+".text",
        FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
    writer.Write(item.Name);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are using `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, use `FileMode.Append`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new file each time you process a zip file entry, open the file outside the while loop and close it after the loop, like so:

```
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(AddonFile));
ZipEntry item;

FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(
    @"resource\texts\"+ Path.GetFileName(AddonFile)+".text",
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);

while ((item = zip.GetNextEntry()) != null)
{
    writer.Write(item.Name);
}
writer.Close();
```